# How to build object from string javascript

Tags: javascript

I have string

```
let str = "class1.class2.class3=d23dasdasd23dasdasdas".
```

How can I build an object from this string ?

I need:

```
    {
        "class1" : {
            "class2": {
                "class3": "d23dasdasd23dasdasdas"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try some code, it usually helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `reduceRight` method by passing a *callback* function as argument.

```js
let obj ="class1.class2.class3=d23dasdasd23dasdasdas";
let [keys, value] = obj.split('=');
keys = keys.split('.')
let result = keys.reduceRight((obj, elem) => ({[elem]: Object.keys(obj).length === 0 ? value : obj }), {});
console.log(result);
```